# Is there a difference between for all and for every in the definition of uniform convergence?

Tags: terminology, uniform-convergence

For example, when my prof defined pointwise convergence and uniform convergence he said something in the line of

pointwise convergence: for every $x$ in set $K$, the sequence $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$

uniform convergence: the sequence $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ for all $x$ in set $K$

Now these sounds Exactly the same to me! What is the main difference and can anything be worded better?

Comment: The last definition is wrong. Please look up at Wikipedia.

Comment: @user251257 can you provide a quick fix?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence

Comment: Those statements *do* mean the same thing, so your paraphrase of these types of convergence is wrong. Pointwise convergence means $\forall \epsilon\forall x\exists N (n\geq N\implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon)$ whereas uniform convergence means $\forall\epsilon\exists N\forall x (n\geq N\implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon)$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic can provide quick fix?

Comment: @EmotionallyVulnerableLlama: ??? I just provided a quick fix.

Comment: @EmotionallyVulnerableLlama: the point is that for pointwise convergence, $N$ depends on both $\epsilon$ and $x$, whereas for uniform convergence, it depends only on $\epsilon$: you can control the error for all $x$ at once.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Can provide adjustment to the sentence "the sequence $fn(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ for all $x$ in set $K$?" danke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you're right, they're the same thing. The problem is that the definition you gave of uniform convergence is wrong. I don't know how deep to go then I'll explain everything. When you say that $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ you are saying that the real succession of the $f_n(x)$ terms converges to the real value $f(x)$, or $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$. Here you are considering $x$ as a fixed point and you are "moving" n and that is why it's called pointwise convergence.

Instead you say that the succession of functions $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ if the uniform norm of their difference tends to zero for $n \rightarrow \infty$. You consider then a difference between functions and not adifference between real values as you did before in the pointwise convergence. You here have to show that 
$$ ||f_n -f || \rightarrow 0 $$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$. Notice that I didn't write  $||f_n(x) -f(x) ||$ but $||f_n -f ||$ because I'm treating the functions themselves and not their value for a certain x. (Hope you know how the uniform norm is defined).